# cryptopp foreign library dependency

Tags: c++, cabal, archlinux, crypto++, happstack

I tried to install `happstack-server-tls` package via cabal on Arch Linux (3.12.9), but got this error:

```
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring happstack-server-tls-7.1.0...
Failed to install happstack-server-tls-7.1.0
Last 10 lines of the build log ( /home/boris/.cabal/logs/happstack-server-tls-7.1.0.log ):
Configuring happstack-server-tls-7.1.0...
/bin/sh: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)
setup-Cabal-1.16.0-x86_64-linux-ghc-7.6.3: Missing dependency on a foreign
library:
* Missing C library: cryptopp
This problem can usually be solved by installing the system package that
provides this library (you may need the "-dev" version). If the library is
already installed but in a non-standard location then you can use the flags
--extra-include-dirs= and --extra-lib-dirs= to specify where it is.
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
happstack-server-tls-7.1.0 failed during the configure step. The exception
was:
ExitFailure 1
```

After seeing this error message for the first time, I have installed `crypto++` via pacman. But it didn't help me.

I even tried this:

```
$ whereis libcryptopp.a                                                                                           
libcryptopp: /usr/lib/libcryptopp.so
$ cabal install happstack-server-tls --extra-include-dirs=/usr/lib/ --extra-lib-dirs=/usr/lib/
```

But still no luck.

I checked, if crypto++ lib works with this test.cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

#include "cryptopp/integer.h"
using CryptoPP::Integer;

int main( int, char** ) {

    Integer i;

    cout << "i: " << i << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

And with `g++ -g3 -ggdb -O0 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused -o test test.cpp -lcryptopp -pthread` test.cpp compiled well.

Then I tried to

```
$ cd /usr/lib
$ g++ -fpic -nostartfiles -nostdlib -shared libcryptopp.so -o libcryptopp.dylib
```

But again, still no luck.

Have someone faced this problem? Has it any solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

run `cabal unpack happstack-server-tls` to fetch and unpack the source code in a local directory. Then edit the `happstack-server-tls.cabal` and try removing these lines:

```
if !os(darwin)
    Extra-Libraries: cryptopp
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It helped me. But why has it happened?

Comment: I'm not really sure. Something complicated involving linking and template haskell and error messages I think?