# How to install "cryptopp" on Ubuntu 13.10 for Haskell?

Tags: haskell, cabal, clckwrks

When trying to install clckwrks, I get the following error after a couple `cabal install` tries:

```
~/Progs/clckwrks/clckwrks$ cabal install
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring happstack-server-tls-7.1.0...
cabal: Missing dependency on a foreign library:
* Missing C library: cryptopp
....
```

Why can I not find this library in the repositories? Is it the Crypto++ from cryptopp.com? Oddly enough there's no mention of this on the getting started guide at http://clckwrks.com/page/view-page-slug/3/get-started .

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to install crypto++. If you'll get the same error after installing this lib, look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343259/cryptopp-foreign-library-dependency) question.

BTW, actually, the problem is in happstack-server-tls, not in clckwrks, so they haven't mentioned it.

*Update*

On server running you can get error about ssl/localhost.key and ssl/localhost.cer. In this case - look for the answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36786/how-to-configure-ssl-in-apache).